# Is there a way to continue/fix this proof of proving a function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

[image]

This problem is from Charles C. Pugh - Real Mathematical Analysis.

To prove $f$ is continuous, the main idea is just to prove the difference $$\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(x_{n})|
\end{align*}$$ can be small enough. Also, we already know that $f_{n}(x_{n})\to f(x)$ . Thus, it's natural to use triangle inequality to have $$\begin{align*}
|f(x)  -f(x_{n})| \leq |f(x) - f_{n}(x_{n})|+ | f_{n}(x_{n}) - f(x_{n})|
\end{align*}$$ And now we need to estimate $|f_{n}(x_{n})-f(x_{n})|$ is small.

Then consider the sequence $\left\{ x_{n},x_{n},x_{n},\cdots \right\}$ which is indeed a sequence converges to $x_{n}$, so by the property stated in the problem, we have $$\begin{align*}
f_{k}(x_{n}) \stackrel{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} f(x_{n})
\end{align*}$$ That is $\forall \epsilon, \forall n, \exists K: \forall k \geq K \implies |f_{k}(x_{n})-f(x_{n})|< \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ . Also, this $K$ can always exist by we already know that $f_{k}(x_{n}) \stackrel{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} f(x_{n})$

Then now I have  $$\begin{align*}
|f_{n}(x_{n})-f(x_{n})| \leq |f(x_{n}) - f_{k}(x_{n})| + |f_{k}(x_{n}) - f_{n}(x_{n})|
\end{align*}$$ where $|f(x_{n})-f_{k}(x_{n})|$ can be small enough. Then the part I got stuck is how should I make $$\begin{align*}
|f_{k}(x_{n})-f_{n}(x_{n})|
\end{align*}$$ be small enough. Indeed I know the sequence $\left\{ f_{k}(x_{n}) \right\}$ is Cauchy since it converges to $f(x_{n})$ . Then it means that $$\begin{align*}
\forall \epsilon> 0, \forall n , \exists N: \forall p \in   \mathbb{N}, \forall m >  N \implies |f_{m+p}(x_{n})-f_{m}(x_{n})| < \epsilon
\end{align*}$$
Then for $|f_{n}(x_{n})-f_{k}(x_{n})|$  this part. I think that $k$ can be large enough (more specifically, $k> \max\limits(K, N)$ ) However, $n$ can't move freely, since as the statement of being Cauchy, I think $N$ actually depends on $n$. Thus if $n$ varies, $N$ varies. As a result, I can't guarantee that $k,n$ above are both larger than $N$ so that $|f_{n}(x_{n})-f_{k}(x_{n})|$ can be small enough.

Any help on this? Or can you continue my idea to fix this proof? Thank you very much.

Comment: When a direct proof doesn't seem to work out, try going by contradiction.